# Issue Installing Cypress

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress

i have installed node js and set environment variables .
I have issue using npm install cypress , i also used --force but the issue was not fixed
the npm command freeze and then shows error
This is the screenshot
[image]

Could you please advise

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the error? I don't see any, the screenshot means the installation is in progress. Perhaps it only takes some time?

Comment: No actually it freezes for a long time

Comment: Try to get more visibility - some verbose output if possible, see network traffic, etc. Perhaps you can try a different network, some connections might be blocked on some networks.